# how to count bookmarks in a pdf file using a batch file?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

how to count bookmarks in a pdf file using a batch file? or any other easy way in user mode not in Admin mode. (wherein can't install or cant use Run Command). Somebody help...

Comment: Do you have a full version of Acrobat or just a PDF viewer? What OS are you using?

Comment: I have Adobe Acrobat 7 Professional and even im having Adobe 10 professional also in other machine... and im using windows xp